# Отставание данных в отчёте от актуальных в яндекс метрике

Tags: javascript, html, yandex-metrika-api

Добрый день всем! Отставание данных в отчёте от актуальных на час в Яндекс.Метрике. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Написать в саппорт-метрики, получить ответ там.